# I try to using wpfextendtoolkit, but my vs not show any tool

Tags: c#, wpf, toolkit, xceed

Can some one explain for me why my wpfextendtoolkit not work
I already rebuild the solution. 
I add using Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit;  in  the .cs file.
What am i missing here? 
The

[image]

Comment: i using Nuget to get the package and it work. But it also include many item i dont need so far. can i just remove them for now?

Comment: do one thing, uninstall it. then install it in some other drive like F: and then use it. I installed it in f: drive and it is working without issues whatsoever. I downloaded it from website directly.http://snag.gy/EZtgk.jpg